# count items in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two UL lists that I handle with Jquery sortable. The first list contains some items and the second is empty. User can drop items from first to second list or back. Part of my function:

```
    receive: function(event,ui){
        //var clocks = $('#sortable4').sortable('serialize');
        //console.log(clocks);
        var howMany = $('#sortable4').length;
        console.log(howMany);
        if (howMany >0) {
            $('#span_clocks').removeClass('spn_normal').addClass('spn_success').text('Hai scelto '+howMany+' myPage per questo template');
        }else{
            $('#span_clocks').removeClass('spn_success').addClass('spn_normal').text('Trascina i MyPage disponibili nel riquadro a destra per assegnarli a questo template.');          
        }
```

receive event applies some css to the page when at least one element is on the second list. Variable howMany returns 1 each time an element is moved from list one to list two and not the real length of the list.
What am I missing? The api guide is not helpful for me or maybe I cannot find the point. I think I have to use another handler and not receive to get this.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Assuming your "list" is a `ul` you need to chek the length of the `li` collection -- `$('#sortable4 li').length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like with `var howMany = $('#sortable4').length;` you are counting "how many ULs" and not "how many LIs".

Better do something like:

```
var howMany = $('#sortable4').find('> li').length;
```